# How to get text from input text for object of class in zend?

Tags: zend-framework, pimcore

I create object of class in pimcore CMS. I want to know how to get text from input for object of class in zend framework?

Answer (score 1):

Just use getter generated in your Object class:

```php
$object = MyGeneratedObjectClass::getById($id);
$text = $object->getMyInput();
```